# How can I edit my js app to include multiple product sections?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am thinking how to edit my javascript app so that I can have multiple product sections on the same page.

Normally I can figure out where to find the answer with research, but I cant seem to pinpoint what I am trying to do into a single search. I am very new to javascript and built this by following a tutorial.

I was thinking it could be as simple as copy and pasting the //display products section, but I am near definite that is my newbie mind taking control.

I want to have a top selling section which I already have, but then I want to have a section for each type of product (up to 5 different types and max 50 products), which would include some of the products in the top selling section. Problem is how the current app seems to call and display all the products in the order of the JSON file (or in this case, contentful api).

Another thought I had was copying the entire script where it mentions the products, changing the variable names and IDs to differentiate, but I know for sure that would then be unable to integrate with the cart you see below.

I have a feeling I havent done a good job of asking my question or what explaining what I need due to my knowledge of the subject, so I am more than happy to answer any more questions!

I begun this project as a goal to learn as much as I could about Javascript and to also help a friend out. So I am avoiding any programs/software which will do it all for me :)

```
    //------------------------------------Shopping Cart Index.HTML------------------------------------//

const client = contentful.createClient({
  // This is the space ID. A space is like a project folder in Contentful terms
  space: "10em3xu8z5p9",
  // This is the access token for this space. Normally you get both ID and the token in the Contentful web app
  accessToken: "R-ViP0OYMKt82BbkpBLAmv4r_KlFk1GvBbUh8aQ9CS8"
});


//variables

const cartBtn = document.querySelector('.cart-btn');
const closeCartBtn = document.querySelector('.close-cart');
const clearCartBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-cart');
const cartDOM = document.querySelector('.cart');
const cartOverlay = document.querySelector('.cart-overlay');
const cartItems = document.querySelector('.cart-items');
const cartTotal = document.querySelector('.cart-total');
const closeVartBtn = document.querySelector('.close-cart');
const cartContent = document.querySelector('.cart-cont');
const productsDOM = document.querySelector('.products-center');

// cart
let cart = [];

// buttons
let buttonsDOM = [];

// getting products
class Products{
  async getProducts(){
    try {

      let contentful = await client.getEntries()
      content_type: 'brewBerryProducts'

      // local data
      // let result = await fetch("products.json");
      // let data = await result.json();

      let products = contentful.items;
      products = products.map(item =>{
        const {title,price} = item.fields;
          const {id} = item.sys
            const image = item.fields.image.fields.file.url;
            return {title,price,id,image}
          })
          return products
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}

// display products
class UI{
  displayProducts(products){
    let result = '';
    products.forEach(product => {
      result += `
      <!-- Product 1 -->
      <article class="product">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src=${product.image} alt="Chilli Oil" class="product-img">
          <button class="bag-btn" data-id=${product.id}>
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            add to cart
          </button>
        </div>
        <h3>${product.title}</h3>
        <h4>£${product.price}</h4>
      </article>
      <!-- End of Product 1 -->
      `;
    });
    productsDOM.innerHTML = result;
  }
  getBagButtons(){
    const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".bag-btn")];
    buttonsDOM = buttons;
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      let id = button.dataset.id;
      let inCart = cart.find(item => item.id === id);
      if(inCart){
        button.innerText = "In Cart";
        button.disable = true
      } 
      button.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
        event.target.innerText = "In Cart";
        event.target.disabled = true;
        // get product from products
        let cartItem = {...Storage.getProduct(id), amount:1};
        // add product to the cart
        cart = [...cart,cartItem];
        console.log(cart);
        // save cart in local storage
        Storage.saveCart(cart);
        // set cart values
        this.setCartValues(cart);
        // display cart item
        this.addCartItem(cartItem);
        // show the cart
        this.showCart();
      });
    });
  }
  setCartValues(cart){
    let tempTotal = 0;
    let itemsTotal = 0;
    cart.map(item =>{
      tempTotal += item.price * item.amount;
      itemsTotal += item.amount
    })
    cartTotal.innerText = parseFloat(tempTotal.toFixed(2));
    cartItems.innerText = itemsTotal;
  }
  addCartItem(item) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("cart-item");
    div.innerHTML = `<img src=${item.image} alt="Chilli Oil">
                    <div>
                      <h4>${item.title}</h4>
                      <h5>£${item.price}</h5>
                    <span class="remove-item" data-id=${item.id}>remove</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up" data-id=${item.id}></i>
                      <p class="item-amount">${item.amount}</p>
                      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" data-id=${item.id}></i>
                    </div>`;
    cartContent.appendChild(div);
  }
  showCart() {
    cartOverlay.classList.add('transparentBcg');
    cartDOM.classList.add('showCart');
  }
  setupAPP() {
    cart = Storage.getCart();
    this.setCartValues(cart);
    this.populateCart(cart);
    cartBtn.addEventListener('click',this.showCart);
    closeCartBtn.addEventListener('click',this.hideCart)
  }
  populateCart(cart){
    cart.forEach(item =>this.addCartItem(item));
  }
  hideCart(){
    cartOverlay.classList.remove('transparentBcg');
    cartDOM.classList.remove('showCart');
  }
  cartLogic() {
    // clear cart button
    clearCartBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
      this.clearCart();
    });
    // cart functionality
    cartContent.addEventListener('click',event=>{
      if(event.target.classList.contains('remove-item'))
      {
        let removeItem = event.target;
        let id = removeItem.dataset.id;
        cartContent.removeChild(removeItem.parentElement.parentElement);
        this.removeItem(id);
      }
      else if(event.target.classList.contains("fa-chevron-up")){
        let addAmount = event.target;
        let id = addAmount.dataset.id;
        let tempItem = cart.find(item => item.id===id);
        tempItem.amount = tempItem.amount + 1;
        Storage.saveCart(cart);
        this.setCartValues(cart);
        addAmount.nextElementSibling.innerText = tempItem.amount;
      }
      else if(event.target.classList.contains("fa-chevron-down")){
        let lowerAmount = event.target;
        let id = lowerAmount.dataset.id;
        let tempItem = cart.find(item => item.id===id);
        tempItem.amount = tempItem.amount - 1;
        if(tempItem.amount > 0){
Storage.saveCart(cart);
this.setCartValues(cart);
lowerAmount.previousElementSibling.innerText = tempItem.amount;
        } else {
          cartContent.removeChild(lowerAmount.parentElement.parentElement);
          this.removeItem(id);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  clearCart(){
    let cartItems = cart.map(item => item.id);
    cartItems.forEach(id => this.removeItem(id));
    console.log(cartContent.children);
    while(cartContent.children.length>0){
      cartContent.removeChild(cartContent.children[0])
    }
    this.hideCart();
  }
  removeItem(id) {
    cart = cart.filter(item => item.id !==id);
    this.setCartValues(cart);
    Storage.saveCart(cart);
    let button = this.getSingleButton(id);
    button.disabled = false;
    button.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>add to cart`;
  }
  getSingleButton(id) {
    return buttonsDOM.find(button => button.dataset.id === id);
  }
}

// local storage
class Storage {
  static saveProducts(products) {
      localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
  }
  static getProduct(id) {
      let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
      return products.find(product => product.id === id);
  }
  static saveCart(cart){
    localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
  }
  static getCart() {
    return localStorage.getItem('cart')?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')):[]
  }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
  const ui = new UI();
  const products = new Products()
  // setup app
  ui.setupAPP();
    // get all products
    products.getProducts() .then(products => {
      ui.displayProducts(products);
      Storage.saveProducts(products);
    }).then(()=>{
      ui.getBagButtons();
      ui.cartLogic();
    });
  });
```